# Linux; Kernel interrupts impacts on CPU-load

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, kernel-module

I have implementet [Derek Molloys Loadable Kernel Module](http://derekmolloy.ie/kernel-gpio-programming-buttons-and-leds/) (see listing 4). It uses a Kernel Module to register a kernel interrupt on a GPIO rising edge. So every time there is a rising edge on a certain GPIO-pin, an interrupt (ISR) runs. The only thing happening in the interrupt, is counting up an integer. I'm running debian on the beaglebone (Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone47).

I put a square wave signal onto the GPIO, causing the interrupts to trigger with a certain frequency. If I turn the frequency up to somewhere above 10kHz, the processor freezes. I don't expect the the processor to be able to follow up to this pace, but I expect the load to be visible by the "top" command. Here is what I see:
[image: screenshot from top]
This measurement is taken with 10 kHz kernel interrupts running, but i still only get:

%Cpu(s): 0.0 hi

"hi" is defined as: "time spent servicing hardware interrupts" in man top
**How can that be? How can i measure the impact the kernel interrupt has on the CPU's idletime?**

Comment: By default, `top` only updates per second or two. Maybe that's the problem. Look at `top -d ss.tt` to change that.

Comment: I just tried that, but it didn't change anything on the hi-value. Would not make sense, because the interrupts are running complete continually, so the sample time for top shouldn't make a difference. But thank you for the sugestion :)

Comment: @Wiingaard did you find an answer in the mean time?

Comment: Nope, I stopped working in this field years ago :(